Do there exist integers that can be written as the sum of two powers of the same prime in two ways?
Prof. Peter Cameron has a list of conjectures on his website, one of which is the following (unresolved) one:
There are only six positive integers greater than 2 which can be written as the sum of two powers of the same prime in more than two ways
I fail to see how an integer can be written as the sum of two powers of the same prime in even two ways:-
Suppose it is true for some integer $k$. Then, there exists a prime p and positive integers $m, n, g, h$, such that $m \neq n$ and:
$k = p^m + p^{m + g} = p^n + p^{n + h} \Rightarrow p^{m - n} = \dfrac{1 + p^h}{1 + p^g}$, but this is not possible as $p$ does not divide $1 + p^h$.

They mean $p^a + p^b = q^c + q^d$

In case anyone else is curious, the six numbers are $6,10,12,18,30$ and $132$.

I see how the six numbers given by anankElpis work, but why isn't a seventh number $130=2+128=5+125$ in the list?

@KeithBackman  The goal is more than two ways.  $6=1+5=2+4=3+3$, for example

@MJD Apparently the exponent $0$ not only counts, but is essential. Note that each of the cited examples other than $10$ is $1$ greater than a prime number. I missed that the first time around.

https://oeis.org/A284667 lists eleven such integers.

@nickgard  Again, that list only concerns two such representations.  The conjecture requires at least $3$.

@nickgard: A284667 lists sums for "at least two values" of primes (and positive exponents). Of that list, $6$, $10$, $12$, $18$, $30$, $132$ are each $1$ more than the power of a prime, giving a third decomposition (allowing a zero exponent).

@ZoeAllen Why not give that as an answer?
